# php included file not updating after edit

Tags: php, include, warnings, php-include

I am using Pear Mail to send an email via php.  I first ran into trouble when all the includes didn't work in the Pear Mail library - but found the answer when research showed I needed to change all the file paths to absolute file paths.  I am doing that... BUT, after changing one and refreshing my browser window, the error message did not change:
the line in question:

```
include_once "Net/SMTP.php";
```

and this is the warning I get:

> Warning: include_once(Net/SMTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 348

I changed "Net/SMTP.php" to be: "/home/username/php/Net/SMTP.php" in the file path, and I continue to receive that same error.  In a previous change (where I messed up) I got the error and saw the new incorrect file path in the Warning, so I know that part of the message should be at least changing.

I checked many things to make sure I'm not crazy:

1. that my edits went through - I opened the file I edited in 2 separate editors and saw my changes were correct.
2. that my file path was correct - again, checked both separate editors to make sure the file path was correct.
3. searched for a duplicate file name in another folder - in case I was editing the wrong file.

And I did the following to try to fix it:

1. changed the file path to something different
2. changed all "include_once" to "include" (in case my browser didn't want to reload a file
3. refreshed the heck out of my browser/cleared the cache/viewed on several browsers and computers
4. Googled everything I could think of
5. looked in a real-life paper book for possible newbie mistakes

My intuition tells me my browser isn't refreshing the included files.
But perhaps it's my server that isn't?

My intuition also tells me this is a basic mistake you would learn to avoid on day one.

Any help, clues, leading questions, links, etc... are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Pear Mail hasn't been updated in five years. Use [PHPMailer](http://PHPmailer.worxware.com) instead.

Comment: And did you try hitting CTRL-F5 to reload the page ?

Comment: The browser has no way of knowing what happens inside the PHP code, so it doesn't care whether you've included a file, hard-coded it etc.
It can cache the complete page, though. But if it doesn't happen in other computers then it's not the case.
Did you make sure you've updated the file on the server (maybe its upload was skipped)?

Comment: ? @JayBlanchard if this is not helpful, pls let me know so I can amend to assist you. If you prefer, I can remove my suggestions to debug the error. Please let me know. thanks. My answer is not removed.

Comment: Add your suggestions here in the comments section.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Still not working, but going through suggestions now.
@Imashcha I opened the file from the server on two different editors on this computer and on my phone - both showed the appropriate changes I made :(   I checked the permissions on everything, and that all seemed fine.

Comment: Possibly there is some caching mechanism on your server. Try renaming the file.

Comment: I renamed all my files used in this (including the php file I visit in my browser) and I still get this same error (with the same filename)!!  It should be giving me the same error type, but not being able to find includes further down the stream

And now, even more disturbing: I can't find where smtp.php is called originally.  I searched through all the Pear Mail library files and it's not there.  I'm POSITIVE I had seen it before.  I think I may have lost my mind.  

I think the only way to solve this is to start from scratch.  Thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in the command line window:

```
pear install Mail

pear install Net_SMTP
```

Then your paths are not required any more since PHP takes care of it.
If you do not have installed pear before you of course have to do it first.

https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php

Comment: This might have worked, but I installed PHPMailer instead and that is working fine.